# Is the Helicoid the preimage of a regular value?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I am asked to prove or disprove the claim. So far I have tried manipulating the component functions of the usual parametrization, but I get nowhere since all my relations involve dividing some component by another and thus when $x=0$ or $y=0$ everything goes really worng.

Do any of you know how to proceed in such cases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the precise notion of helicoid you're working with. Is it a closed subset of $\Bbb R^3$? Does it have boundary? You might also expand a little on the efforts you've made. They make very little sense as it stands.